# What's so wrong with the ML350 G5?

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant

It seems there a number of differences between the HP ML350 G5 and G6

- G6 has more RAM slots
- G6 runs leaner, cooler, and quieter
- When considering an equally spec'd G6 (CPUs, RAM, HD), the G6 is 3x the price
- The G5 doesn't look quite so fly

For the first server is SMB environment, are there any other reasons to avoid the G5?  Bang for the buck with the G5 is impressive...

Comment: I would say as the G6 is a generation newer that the G5 machines the technology has evolved. Bearning in mind HP is in G8 now, there's nothing wrong with a G5/G6 server if it's in a good state.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it. Are you working within a specific budget? A ML350 G5 can be had for less than $500.

Comment: Yeah, we've got a very limited budget.  The barebones G6 is significantly more than a loaded refurbished G5.

Comment: There is no difference except the performance. Also check if this G5 will handle SATA III drives > 2TB with firmware upgrade.

Comment: I'm disappointed in all of you... did nobody catch the Fareast Movement "Lke a G6" reference?

Comment: @Jonathan Nope...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you buy a PC from 2009 in 2012? Just know and understand what you're getting...

The ML350 G5 is simply an old generation product (active from 2006-2009). The G6 is newer. Both have been eclipsed by more modern options. So you're talking about a major shift in processing architecture (going from Intel 5400-series to the [5500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nehalem_%28microarchitecture%29) and [5600](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nehalem_%28microarchitecture%29#Westmere) available in the G6).

The machines look nearly identical in tower form.

[image]

They're both relatively quiet. The ILO 2 technology is the same between the two servers. The G6 will have Hyperthreading, Turbo Boost, more RAM options and be a better virtualization platform overall. The RAID controller and storage subsystem is a bit better as well. Keep in mind that the tower servers are no longer HP's primary focus, so the ML350 did not have a G7 equivalent.

Comment: Thanks ewwhite. Sorry to be pestering you with all of these Proliant questions just trying to make an informed decision.

Answer (score 0):

The move from the Xeon 54xx series to the 55xx series was a major leap in the design of Intel-based dual-socket systems.

As well as the performance per clock improvements going from Harpertown to Nahelm the 54xx systems used a shared front side bus and memory controller which could limit memory bandwidth while the 55xx systems had a memory controller on each processor. Most significantly the type of memory used was changed from FBDIMM to DDR3 and the max memory was increased significantly.

And then the 56xx came along offering 6 cores per socket on the same socket as the 55xx.